# JSP Cannot find resource

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm writing something extremely with JSPs and Java Servlets, just to get used to them.

I have a Java servlet called "LoginServlet" inside "Java Resources" and, inside my web content folder I have

```
<form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
```

which is inside a html file. However, eclipse tells me that this resource cannot be found. I've tried `action="userLoginPackage.LoginServlet"`,but that does not work. Note, that everything is in the same project, but I don't think that the stuff in WebContent is in the same package as LoginServlet, which could be the problem. However, if it is, I'm not sure where else to put html files(where should I put them?)

I understand this may be difficult to solve without knowing the structure of my project- please let me know if there is any other information I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you define your "LoginServlet" in the web.xml? What's the web.xml look like? You need to define a servlet in the web.xml before you can call it.

Comment: there is no web.xml in WEB-INF - how do I go about creating one?

Comment: You project is a web app, you will need one. I don't know how you create your project, and what is your project structure looks like. The web.xml file is located in the WEB-INF directory of your Web application. You can manually create one. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html

Comment: is there a benefit to using this as opposed to annotations?

Comment: annotations also work fine if you define the mapping correctly. It is your project requirement, does your project need to be run in Java 5? Or it will always run in Java 6 or above? I believe the servlet annotation only works for Servlet 3.0 which is in Java 6

Answer (score 0):

Your "LoginServlet" should be placed inside "Java Resources/src" folder. And your html file should be in "WebContent" folder.